# How to make the Handler method be destroyed when the activity finishes?

Tags: android, android-activity, handler

At the end of this activity, the timer from the Handler method continues.
How to make the Handler method be destroyed when the activity finishes?

```
                 Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            mTextViewCountDown.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        }
                    }, 55000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I did not "destroy" the method if I leave the `Activity`, but the method does something only when `Activity` is active

Something like this :

```java
// Variable of your activity
private static boolean active = false;
```

```java
Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // do something only if Activity is active
                            if(active) {
                                mTextViewCountDown.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            }
                        }
                    }, 55000);
```

and set the value of `active` in the `onStart` / `onStop` methods :

```java
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        active = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        active = false;
    }
```

this way the code inside `handler.postdelay` will be executed only when your `Activity` is active

Answer (score 0):

you can you use onDestory(); lifecycle method.this method calls when an activity going to finish and in this activity lifecycle method you and stop the handler like this

````
@Override 
protected void onDestroy() {

Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable());

super.onDestroy();

}```
````